# Local image URL binding to panorama title

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, panorama-control

Before marking it duplicate, please read my whole question & efforts. In my app I am first downloading the image & saving in **[local folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder%28v=win.10%29.aspx) not in isolated storage**. Then I am trying to bind the local image URL (`ms-appdata:///local/53077cab6ed10b742b00000c_cloud.png`) to panorama title but it's not working. Can any anyone tell me what is wrong. Given are my attempts based on past SO answers.

## 1:

```xml
<phone:Panorama Title="{Binding Settings.Logo.HighResolution, Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}">
    <phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="130,80,0,0">
                <Image Height="200">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}" />
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
</phone:Panorama>
```

## 2:

```xml
<phone:Panorama Title="{Binding Settings.Logo.HighResolution, Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}">
    <phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="130,80,0,0">
                <Image Height="200" Source="{Binding}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
</phone:Panorama>
```

## 3:

Same as #1 & #2 but without converter.

I used two type of conversion none of it worked.

```csharp
public class DebugConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new Uri(value.ToString());
        //return new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(value.ToString()));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use such a Converter:

```
public class DebugConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
     BitmapImage temp = new BitmapImage();

     using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
     using (IsolatedStorageFileStream file = ISF.OpenFile((string)value, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        temp.SetSource(file);
     return temp;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  } 
}
```

I haven't tried the above code, but if your image is saved to Isolated Storage this should work. I only don't know what you pass with value - it should be a string pointing file "53077cab6ed10b742b00000c_cloud.png" without ms-appdata.

**EDIT** - remark

As I've checked file created in LocalFolder with such a code (for example):

```
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile sampleFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("dataFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

is created in IsolatedStorage root folder of the App (it could be created the same with IsolatedStorageFile). So those files should be accessible via IsolatedStorage.

Comment: I am not using Isolated Storage, I am using [local folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder(v=win.10).aspx).

Comment: @Xyroid As I've checked file created in LocalStorage is the same as created with IS. So it should be accesible with above code. Can you try it? Or better check with IsolatedStorageExplorer?

Comment: Yeah, it worked finally. Though looking for more better solution, otherwise will mark your answer as accepted. I also tried `StorageFile` API in converter but async APIs are not supported in that :(

Comment: @Xyroid You can also bypass Converter and do it via property which getter will return BitmapImage (as the code in Converter). But it is nearly the same.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this to get hold of images attached as content to the project

```
var resStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(PlaceHolderImageUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

if(resStream != null && resStream.Stream != null && resStream.Stream.Length > 0)
    WriteableBitmap PlaceHolderWB =  PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(resStream.Stream);
```

I have a converter for this but you can do how you see fit..

Comment: I am downloading the image from Internet when user presses "refresh" in the app, it's not part of project as resource or content. Then after I save in local storage so I can have it offline. I want to do purely via binding. Will you give me solution based ob it?

Comment: I already tried `BitmapImage`. Please see commented line in `DebugConverter`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the coding4fun SuperImage instead of a regular Image as this has support for isolated storage as a location for images.

https://coding4fun.codeplex.com/

Comment: I am not using Isolated Storage, I am using [local folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder(v=win.10).aspx).

Comment: if it uses ms-appdata, SuperImage supports that too I believe.